# How to upload a file in Katalon

Tags: katalon-studio, uploading

So I want the automated test case to find the file and upload it. This is what I found with my research but no luck with it.

```
WebUI.openBrowser('C:\\\\Users\\\\User\\\\Desktop\\\\Katalon Articles\\\\File Upload\\\\UploadFile.html')

'Maximize the window\r\n'
WebUI.maximizeWindow()

'Uploading the File using Send Keys method by passing the File path'
WebUI.sendKeys(findTestObject('Upload File'), 'C:\\\\Users\\\\Public\\\\Pictures\\\\Sample Pictures\\\\Desert.jpg')

'Capturing the file name after upload and storing it in a variable'
FilePath = WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('Upload File'), 'value')

'Verifying the Actual path and Expected path of file'
WebUI.verifyMatch(FilePath, 'C:\\fakepath\\Desert.jpg', false)
```

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-upload-file.html?

Comment: What isn't working? Do you have some errors? If so, please post error stack trace.